# Отрисовка WriteableBitmap

Tags: c#, wpf

В программе необходимо быстро рисовать на изображении. Для этого выбрал WriteableBitmap, с BackBuffer произвожу нужные манипуляции. И всё благополучно отрисовывается, пока размер изображения не превышает какой-то предел в районе 1500 пикселей. Свыше этого размера вместо нужной фигуры, появляется нечто другое.

```
writeable.Lock();
IntPtr buff = writeable.BackBuffer;
unsafe
{
    byte* pbuff = (byte*)buff.ToPointer();
    ...
}
writeable.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, (int)writeable.Width, (int)writeable.Height));
writeable.Unlock();
```

[image: Вверху неверный результат отрисовки, внизу как должно примерно выглядеть (круглая кисть)]

Вверху неверный результат отрисовки, внизу как должно примерно выглядеть (круглая кисть). Если обновлять не всё изображение, а только изменяемую область, то результат идентичен обновлению всего изображения.
В чём заключается проблема? Это особенность BackBuffer или ещё какие-то ограничения на размер WriteableBitmap? И что с этим делать, если необходима очень быстрая отрисовка на изображениях в 15-30 мегапикселей?

Answer (score 0):

Дело было в способе доступа к BackBuffer.
Вот так не работает на больших изображениях:

```
writeable.Lock();
IntPtr buff = writeable.BackBuffer;
unsafe
{
    byte* pbuff = (byte*)buff.ToPointer();

    pbuff[Index * 3 + 0] = (byte)(B);
    pbuff[Index * 3 + 1] = (byte)(G);
    pbuff[Index * 3 + 2] = (byte)(R);
}
writeable.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, writeable.PixelWidth, writeable.PixelHeight));
writeable.Unlock();
```

А вот так работает:

```
writeable.Lock();
unsafe
{
    long pBackBuffer = (long)writeable.BackBuffer;
    int stride = writeable.BackBufferStride;

    int offset = (int)(RelativeY * stride + RelativeX * 3);
    long pBackBufferWithOffset = pBackBuffer + offset;
    *((byte*)pBackBufferWithOffset + 0) = (byte)(B);
    *((byte*)pBackBufferWithOffset + 1) = (byte)(G);
    *((byte*)pBackBufferWithOffset + 2) = (byte)(R);
}
writeable.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, writeable.PixelWidth, writeable.PixelHeight));
writeable.Unlock();
```

Важно использовать именно long, а не int.